# using MYSQL count function to get two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using the following query to retrieve data from a database:

```
   SELECT product_Id, COUNT(product_Id) as count
   FROM my_sales
   GROUP BY product_Id
   ORDER BY count DESC
```

in phpmyadmin it looks like this:

```
_____________________________________
    Product_ID    |       count              
__________________|__________________
        12        |         13
        13        |         21
        14        |         24
```

The PHP Code im using looks like this:

```
$res = $connVar->prepare($query);   //the query described above
$res->execute();                               
$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ( $row  = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
{
    $data[] = $row;//return the information from the database as an array
    echo $data[0]['product_Id']; //trying to target specific indexes of an associative array :/
    echo $data[0]['count'];
}
```

What really needs to happen is that I can store each row as variables so that I can say, print out in php how much stock is left for a particular product.

Been looking on stackoverflow for around 4 hours now and about to give up. There are a lot of questions available about returning the whole dataset within one variable but thats not what i need.

Any help?

Comment: You don't need to use variables. You can just echo like you are doing. Your use of `fetch` and the `while` loop need to be adjusted. Here is a link to a [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) Take a look at how they use `for` or `while`

Comment: Actually i got it myself after around 5 hours now. I will post the answer shortly